# How to extract URLs matching a pattern

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract URLs from a webpage with the following pattern :

> 'http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/????/governor/??/*-*.html'

My current code extracts all the links. How could I change my code to only extract URLs that match the pattern? Thank you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def find_governor_races(html):
    url = html
    base_url = 'http://www.realclearpolitics.com/'
    page = requests.get(html).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')  
    links = []
    for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            links.append(a['href'])
find_governor_races('http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/2010_elections_governor_map.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a [regular expression pattern](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) as an `href` argument value for the `.find_all()`:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"http://www.realclearpolitics.com\/epolls/\d+/governor/.*?/.*?.html")
links = soup.find_all("a", href=pattern)
```